# Wildcards in grizzly HttpHandler's mappings

Tags: java, grizzly

I'm trying to map MyHttpHandler to custom url using grizzly 2.3 web server like this (that should be RESTfull url, like `/entity/42/attribute`):

```
HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
ServerConfiguration config = httpServer.getServerConfiguration();
config.addHttpHandler(new MyHttpHandler(), "/entity/*/attribute");
```

It does not work. How can I do it in grizzly?

Comment: Looks like no one knows much about grizzly. So, I decided to use netty instead (I know, it's not the same. Netty is more low level). Now I have a primitive routing handler in netty with Patterns, Strings and all I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version 2.3.17 of grizzly-http-server, I see that addHttpHandler(HttpHandler httpHandler, String... mappings) creates HttpHandlerRegistration instances from the mapping Strings:

[ServerConfiguration#addHttpHandler (on grepcode.com)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.3.17/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/ServerConfiguration.java#ServerConfiguration.addHttpHandler%28org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

The Javadoc of the fromString method mentions that "*" wildcards are supported:

[HttpHandlerRegistration#fromString (on grepcode.com)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.3.17/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpHandlerRegistration.java#HttpHandlerRegistration.fromString%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: If you are using Maven you could let your IDE download the sources for the grizzly Maven artifacts and step through the code in the debugger. Maybe there is a bug, or a misunderstanding how the wildcard in the mapping is interpreted.